# Is it possible to sort the columns of an Altair grouped bar chart based on the value of one of the categories?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, data-visualization, altair

I have the following chart -
[image]
I'd like to be able to sort the columns (NOT the individual bars of a single group - I know how to do that already), i.e order the 3 *sub-chart* - if you will - based on the value of any category(`a`,`b` or `c`) I choose.

I tried using `alt.SortField` and `alt.EncodeSortField`, they move around the charts a bit, but don't actually work if you change the category to see if they actually work.

**Code** -

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

dummy = pd.DataFrame({'place':['Asia', 'Antarctica','Africa', 'Antarctica', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'Africa','Antarctica', 'Asia'],'category':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'],'value':[5,2,3,4,3,5,6,9,5]})
alt.Chart(dummy).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('category'),
    y='value',
    column=alt.Column('place:N', sort=alt.SortField(field='value', order='descending')),
    color='category',
)
```

I know that `alt.Column('place:N', sort=alt.SortField(field='value', order='descending')),` doesn't seem correct, since I am not targeting any category, so I tried `x=alt.X('category', sort=alt.SortField(field='c', order='descending')),` too, but it doesn't work either.

**Expected Output** (assuming descending order)-

- If I want to order by 'c', then middle column should be first, followed by left and finally right column.
- It already seems ordered by 'b'.
- If I want to order by 'a', then right column should be first, followed by left and finally middle column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit involved, but you can do this with a series of transforms:

- a [Calculate Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/calculate.html) to select the value you want to sort on
- a [Join-Aggregate Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/joinaggregate.html) with `argmax` to join the desired values to each group
- another calculate transform to pull-out the specific field within this result that you would like to sort by

It looks like this, first sorting by `"c"`:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

dummy = pd.DataFrame({'place':['Asia', 'Antarctica','Africa', 'Antarctica', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'Africa','Antarctica', 'Asia'],'category':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'],'value':[5,2,3,4,3,5,6,9,5]})
alt.Chart(dummy).transform_calculate(
    key="datum.category == 'c'"
).transform_joinaggregate(
    sort_key="argmax(key)", groupby=['place']
).transform_calculate(
    sort_val='datum.sort_key.value'  
).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('category'),
    y='value',
    column=alt.Column('place:N', sort=alt.SortField("sort_val", order="descending")),
    color='category',
)
```

[image]

Then sorting by `"a"`:

```
alt.Chart(dummy).transform_calculate(
    key="datum.category == 'a'"
).transform_joinaggregate(
    sort_key="argmax(key)", groupby=['place']
).transform_calculate(
    sort_val='datum.sort_key.value'  
).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('category'),
    y='value',
    column=alt.Column('place:N', sort=alt.SortField("sort_val", order="descending")),
    color='category',
)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow....thanks a lot jake. I must ask though, what do you reckon should I read to be able to come up with these solutions and ideas myself? As it turns out this solution works for this dummy data, but it fails in my actual dataset where the data is slightly more involved in the sense that apart from `place` and `category`, there is a temporal column - `day` - for which each `place` and `category` comes multiple times and I need to pick up the **max** values of each category from the `day` and then do the above.

Comment: If you change ``alt.SortField("sort_val")`` to ``alt.EncodingSortField("sort_val", op="max")``, that will sort by the max of the matching values

Comment: It didn't work at first try so I played around a bit....apart from your suggestion of using ```alt.EncodingSortField("sort_val", op="max")```, I also had to **groupby** using both `place` and `day` i.e ```sort_key="argmax(key)", groupby=['place', 'day']``` and voila it worked. Thank you so much helping me out !!